# Modifying Lua Functions

Tags: lua

I am trying to mod a Lua game (CtGW). There is a function, `engine:GetSavegames`, which returns an array of strings, and I cannot access. I need to modify the returned results. I tried the following, but recieved a "function arguments expected near 'engine'" error.

```
getsaves = engine:GetSavegames
engine:GetSavegames = function()
 return getsaves()
end
```

Comment: One thing you could try is `engine.GetSavegames = ...`, that would fix the syntax. Whether this will actually work and do what you want depends on how the rest of the stuff is coded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`engine:GetSavegames` is only valid syntax for method invocation and not for assignments. As @ChrisBeck wrote in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664287/modifying-lua-functions/33665700#comment55102009_33664287), you need to use `engine.GetSavegame`, but you also need to pass any parameters you can get as those will include the actual object.

Something like this may work:

```
local getsaves = engine.GetSavegames
engine.GetSavegames = function(...)
  return getsaves(...)
end
```

This operation is usually called [monkeypatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

Comment: Thanks, this worked on the Lua demo page. But I don't think there are any parameters possible.

Comment: If it's called as `engine:GetSavegames`, there is going to be at least one parameter as this is equivalent to `engine.getSavegames(engine)`, so the code needs to account for that.

Comment: Thanks again, I did need to add that, and have it working now.